# ReNative Error: No WebOS emulator configured

Tags: react-native, webos, lg, renative

I'm working on Renative project and while trying to launch `rnv run -p webos` command I get `Error: No WebOS emulator configured` despite I've correctly installed webOS emulator and can launch it.

Anyone can help and know if I'm missing some step to configure it?